# Compact open sets which are not closed.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Can a nonclosed open subset of a $T_1$ topological space be compact?
I mean an open compact set which is not clopen.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Another example: $[0,1]\cup\{0_2\}$, where $0_2$ is "another copy of $0$".  A basis for the topology consists of all open subsets of $[0,1]$ with its standard topology, along with all sets of the form $\{0_2\}\cup(0,a)$ with $0<a<1$.  (This is a modification of the line with two origins.)

In this space, $[0,1]$ compact, open, and not closed.

Comment: is it $T_1$?     .?

Comment: @CutieKrait: Yes.  Are there any singletons whose closedness isn't clear?

Comment: Why isn't it hausdorff!?

Comment: @CutieKrait: Because all neighborhoods of $0$ & $0_2$ meet.  (Or because it has a compact nonclosed subset.)

Answer (score 15):

Consider cofinite topology on an infinite set, it is $T_1$ and every set is compact. In particular nonempty open sets which are not closed.