# A compact set, which is not closed.

Tags: analysis, compactness

I'm looking for a compact set, which is not closed.

I read somewhere that $Z^+$ are compact and not closed, but I don't understand why.

Are there any other examples of compact sets that are not closed and could you please explain?

I know that we can't look in the reals because every compact set in the reals is closed and bounded correct?

Comment: Closed where? ${}$

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304567

Comment: Well, compact subsets of a Hausdorff space are closed… So the example you are looking for will come from a non-Hausdorff space.

Comment: I'm in an analysis class and we haven't talked about Hausdorff spaces or in that link posted it talks about cofinite topology and I haven't learned that yet, either.

Comment: Set of all natural numbers is *not* compact (under the natural topology of $\Bbb{R}$. Note that it is closed under that topology.)

Comment: I'm looking for the opposite.

Comment: Are there any examples not involving Hausdorff or topological spaces?

Comment: To clarify, are you asking for an example which is a metric space?

Answer (score 20):

In any metric space, all compact sets are closed.  To see this, let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, and $Y \subset X$ a non-closed set.  Since $Y$ is not closed, it does not contain all of its limit points, so there exists a point $y \not\in Y$ which is an accumulation point of $Y$.  Then, the collection 
$$\mathscr{U} = \{U_\varepsilon\}_{\varepsilon > 0},$$
where $U_\varepsilon = \{x \in X : d(x,y) > \varepsilon\}$, is an open cover of $Y$.  However, any finite subset of $\mathscr{U}$, for example 
$$\mathscr{V} = \{U_{\varepsilon_1}, \cdots, U_{\varepsilon_n}\}$$
is not a cover of $Y$.  To see this, let $\varepsilon = \min\limits_{i\in\{1, \cdots, n\}}\varepsilon_i$.  Then, the ball around $y$ of radius $\varepsilon$ is disjoint from every set in $\mathscr{V}$ and contains a point of $Y$ (since $y$ was assumed to be a limit point of $Y$).  It follows that $Y$ is not compact.

As Prism mentioned in the comments, we can show that any compact subset of a Hausdorff space (a class of topological spaces which includes metric spaces) must be closed.  So we have to look for a non-Hausdorff (non-metric) counterexample.  One such example is the set $X = \{x_1, x_2, x_3\}$ with the trivial topology $\tau = \{\emptyset, X\}$, where the set $Y = \{x_1\}$ is compact (since *any* open cover of $Y$ is finite), but $Y$ is not closed.

Answer (score 16):

A typical example is $X=\{a, b\}$, with the topology ${\mathscr{T}}=\{ \varnothing, \{a\}, X \}$. Then the subset $\{a\}$

- is compact: every open cover of $\{a\}$ admits a finite cover;
- is not closed, since its complement is not in the topology ${\mathscr{T}}$.
- is actually open.

So a compact set can be open and not closed.

Answer (score 9):

Let $X$ be an infinite set, and equip it with the cofinite topology (i.e., $F \subset X$ is closed iff $F=X$ or $F$ is finite). Then *every* subset of $X$ is compact: if $(U_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in I}$ is any open covering of $E$, then for any fixed $\bar{\alpha} \in I$ the set $U_{\bar{\alpha}}$ contains all but finitely many points of $E$, so fix $U_{\alpha_1}, \dots, U_{\alpha_n}$ that cover these remaining points.

I like this example because $X$ is a $T_1$ space, so in a sense it is "almost" Hausdorff.