# Question about compactness of C[0,1]

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, compactness

I am trying to prove that subset of $C[0,1]$ given as $\{h\in C[0,1]:||h||\leq 1\}$ in supremum metric is not compact. As I know, in that set lays sequence $g_n(x)=x^n$ which converges to non-continuous function (0 everywhere else despite 1). And I came up after some research that this implies that such a subset of $C[0,1]$ can't be compact, be I couldn't find out why. Maybe it's simple but I don't see that. So... I will be really grateful if someone could explain that. Or show other, simple way to prove that statement.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Matthias Klupsch Yes. Sorry for confusion. I've made mistake while writting. Thanks for concern and re-edit was made.

Comment: What do the functions $x^n$ have to do with the set mentioned? Every one of them has norm 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any metric space, every compact set is closed (see for example the first answer of [A compact set, which is not closed.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1070188/a-compact-set-which-is-not-closed)). So if your subset doesn't contain all its limits, it is not closed and therefore cannot be compact.

Comment: Thanks! I've missed it somehow. That clears everything.

Comment: The set under consideration is clearly closed as the norm is continuous... There is no contradiction, since the 'limit' of the sequence is not really a limit since it is not contained in $C[0,1]$.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch  No, the set under consideration is not closed. But I see you altered the problem in a good way in your answer.

Comment: @zhw : You are right, I was under the impression that the defining inequality of the set under consideration wasn't a strict one.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B = \{f \in C[0,1] \:|\: \|f\| \leq 1\} \subseteq C[0,1]$ denote the set under consideration. If $B$ were compact, then every sequence in $B$ would have to have a convergent subsequence (convergent with respect to $\|\cdot\|$) converging to an element in $B$. However the sequence $(g_n)_n$ you found fails to have such a subsequence, since the $\| \cdot \|$-limit would in particular have to be the pointwise limit which is not continuous as you already noticed.